# A class doesn't exist in a namespace, although it does

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a class:

```
namespace MyApp.Data {
public class ApiKeysContext : DbContext ...
```

And in other project in the same solution I have a reference to MyApp.Data.csproj
Though, when making object:

```
var context = new MyApp.Data.ApiKeysContext();
```

Visual Studio says I am missing a reference. What can I do about it?

Comment: have you tried referencing `EntityFramework` in the project where you are trying to use `ApiKeysContext()`

Comment: Please show us the source code for the entire class that that `var context` line exists in. Also please show us a screenshot of the error that is being shown by Visual Studio.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot No, I haven't. Is this how you do in your projects?

Comment: @mjwills Sorry, I'm not having my laptop near me right now

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot Oh, I see now, it's the inheritance

Answer (score 0):

I should probably post an answer for everyone as dumb as me...
You should add a refference not only to the class's project, but to all of it's parent classes.

@TheVillageIdiot should get credits for that one